# Performance testing using Ultimate thread group

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, performance-testing, throughput, threadgroup

I want to use ultimate thread group for my test with 2100 users concurrency and synchronising timer with number of simulated users to group by 100.

Here I want to configure the thread group for 10 mins.

I am not sure how to distribute it across initial delay ,start up time, hold load and shut down time

Answer (score 0):

We cannot suggest anything meaningful because we don't know what is your desired load pattern.

Normally people configure threads arrival/leaving so it would be:

1. [Ramp-up phase](https://dzone.com/articles/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) - so the load would increase gradually, it will allow you to correlate increasing load with the changing metrics like response time, transactions per second, errors per second, etc.
2. "Plateau" phase - check how does system behave under constant sustained load
3. Ramp-down phase - it will allow to check whether system gets back to normal when the load decreases

If you don't have better ideas - go for 33% for ramp-up, plateau and ramp-down, in your case it will be easier to take 3 minutes for ramp-up and ramp-down and 4 minutes for the time to holds the load.

The relevant [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) configuration:

[image]

With regards to the [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer), what it will do is to act as a [rendezvous point](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/LoadRunner/What_is_a_rendezvous_point_.html) for all Samplers in it's [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so given ramp-up of 180 seconds for 2100 users it means that 11.6 users will arrive every second so first request will be executed on 8th second of your test with 100 users then requests will be executed one by one each with 100 users in form of ["spikes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing)